# How to find a robust and performant hyper parameter region?

Tags: robust, hyperparameter

Assume we randomly sampled hyper parameters and for each configuration we evaluated our model on three fixed seeds. What methods are there to obtain a robust and performant hyper parameter configuration from this, including a sensitivity value for each hyper parameter?

One approach would be to fit a polynomial to the score distribution of each hyper parameter individually, and select the hyper parameter values that maximize those polynomials. However, this does not take robustness or dependence between hyper parameters into account.

Another idea would be to fit a polynomial to the score distribution in the space of all hyper parameters and find the maximum. We could employ regularization to find flatter regions and drive the weights of irrelevant hyper parameters close to zero.

I'm sure there is a more principled way to analyze the result of a hyper parameter search to select a robust and performant hyper parameter configuration. What methods would be applicable here?

Comment: There are various methods for tuning hyperparameters that might do what you need. But, I don't quite understand your specific requirements. Can you say more about what you mean by 'robust', and 'sensitivity value'?

Comment: @user20160 Sure! By robust I mean that these parameters consistently result in good scores independent of the seed. By sensitivity I mean that a small change in the hyper parameter value still yields good scores, ie the score surface around the parameter value is flat.

Comment: @user20160 Would you mind to take a look?